# What is the `node_dim` argument referring to in the message passing class?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

In the PyTorch geometric [tutorial for creating Message Passing Networks](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_gnn.html) they have this paragraph at the start when explaining what the class does:

> `MessagePassing(aggr="add", flow="source_to_target", node_dim=-2)`: Defines the aggregation scheme to use `("add", "mean" or "max")` and the flow direction of message passing (either `"source_to_target"` or `"target_to_source"`). Furthermore, the `node_dim` attribute indicates along which axis to propagate.

I don't understand what this `node_dim` is referring to, and why it is -2. I have looked at [the documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#convolutional-layers) for the `MessagePassing` class and it says there that it is the axis which to propagate -- this still doesn't really clarify what we are doing here and why the default is -2 (presumably that is how you propagate information at a node level). Could someone offer some explanation of this to me please?

Comment: just a shot in the dark, dimension perhaps?

Comment: @etch_45 I think I am mostly confused as to why it is -2. I have no intuition why it would be -2 for a node_dim, I also think it is unclear whether node_dim means we are telling it which dimension the nodes are on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After referring to [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/conv/message_passing.html#MessagePassing) and [here](https://pytorch-scatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/scatter.html), I think the thing related to it is **the output of the 'message' function**.
In most cases, the shape of the output is `[edge_num, emb_out]`, and if we set the `node_dim` as -2, it means that we will aggregate along the `edge_num` using indices of the target nodes.
This is exactly the process that aggregates the information from source nodes.
The result after aggregation is `[node_num, emb_out]`.